# How to test the limition size of global offset table with the help of template meta programming?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, code-generation, template-meta-programming, got

I want to test the limition of gcc's [global offset table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table). IIUC, I need tones of external variable or shared library functions to reach the limitation, is it ok to use template meta programming as the codegen tool to get the limition?

If it is not doable with tmp, is there other easy way?

Comment: From the linked article: "Offsets to global variables from dynamic libraries are not known during compile time, this is why they are read from the GOT table during runtime." Since template meta programming happens at compile time, I don't think it is possible to use this for testing the limit.